# mysql remote access ERROR 2003

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

My server is in Google Cloud Platform

[image]

upper "back-end"

and in server, `firewall-cmd --list-all` result is that.

[image]

and `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file,

[image]

port = 3306 and all address(0.0.0.0) can access It.

after `sudo service mysql restart` in server,

If I try `./mysql -h104.199.189.198 -uroot -p{password}` in my computer,

mysql return

`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '104.199.189.198' (60)`.

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding tcp:3306 rule in GCP network.

with korean documents https://brunch.co.kr/@smalljiny/3#comments